# Try to write str to file with special file name "con", but it's printed to stdout

Tags: c, windows, filenames

```
FILE *fp = fopen("./con", "w");
char *s = "hello!";
fwrite(s, sizeof(char), strlen(s), fp);
fclose(fp);
return 0;
```

If my file name is "con", then `fwrite()` will work just like `printf()`.

How does it work?

Comment: It can not be used because it is the name that has been reserved in Win32.

Comment: `con` is the DOS name for the console, i.e. the terminal inside the command window.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg and BLUEPIXY Thanks!

Comment: [Do not use the following reserved names for the name of a file](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows/DOS has a number of [reserved filenames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) including CON, PRN, AUX, CLOCK$, NUL
COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4 LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4 and others.

`CON` is the standard console (output), so that is where the data went.

Credits: @BLUEPIXY  @Joachim Pileborg

Comment: Do you know if there is any special method to use this command successfully in Window 7?  I get NULL back, even if process calling it was run in elevated mode.  (  referring to:  `FILE *fp = fopen("./con", "w");`  )

Comment: @ryyker Unsure.  Perhaps `CON` is all ready open, hence the `NULL` when your code attempts to open it.  Suspect we need to use something like or exactly `stdout` or to close it first.

Comment: Ah.  That would make sense.  (i.e. that stdout would already be open)  After all, we are talking Microsoft.

Comment: @ryyker: Maybe it's the fault of the used `fopen()` implementation as it works with the current versions of MinGW-w64 and VS. What about simply `"con"`?